# Constraints for proving : $a\equiv b\pmod {m_1}, a\equiv b\pmod {m_2} \implies a\equiv b\pmod L$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I have read the stated as a property with no proof. However, here in [Konrad's](http://www.math.uconn.edu/~kconrad/blurbs/ugradnumthy/crt.pdf) article there is a mention, but in context of a different set of equalities: 
 $a \equiv b_1\pmod {m_1}, a \equiv b_2\pmod {m_2}$, i.e. $b_1, b_2$ are different quantities.

Also, the article differs by stating a necessary condition as $(m_1,m_2)=1,$ which is not stated in the text from which I picked it.

Also, my [earlier post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2641265/a-equiv-b-mod-m-1-a-equiv-b-mod-m-2-implies-a-equiv-b-mod-l) has failed to produce any proof for it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will answer the question: for given $m_1$ and $m_2$, find the conditions for $L$ such that the implication $a\equiv b\pmod {m_1}\land a\equiv b\pmod {m_2}\implies a\equiv b\pmod L$ is valid for all $a,b\in\mathbb Z$. If that is not what you mean, please shout.

**Claim**: The condition on $L$ is: $L\mid\operatorname{lcm}(m_1,m_2)$

**Proof**: $a\equiv b\pmod m$ is equivalent to $m\mid(b-a)$, so if you denote $d=b-a$, you are actually asking for conditions on $L$ such that $m_1\mid d$ and $m_2\mid d$ implies $L\mid d$.

Now, $m_1\mid d\land m_2\mid d\Longleftrightarrow \operatorname{lcm}(m_1,m_2)\mid d$, which means that the condition you are looking for is $L\mid\operatorname{lcm}(m_1,m_2)$.

**Note**: The proof of the equivalence $m_1\mid d\land m_2\mid d\Longleftrightarrow \operatorname{lcm}(m_1,m_2)\mid d$ depends on what you already know about $\operatorname{lcm}$. Actually, one definition of $\operatorname{lcm}$ is precisely that *it is the minimal common multiple of $m_1$ and $m_2$*, i.e. (i) It is a multiple (which proves $\Leftarrow$) and (ii) It divides every other multiple (which proves $\Rightarrow$). Depending how $\operatorname{lcm}$ is defined in your book, your mileage may vary.

**Updated to add**: After a discussion in the comments, it has transpired that, apparently, the question here is just to prove that $a\equiv b\pmod{m_1}$ and $a\equiv b\pmod{m_2}$ implies $a\equiv b\pmod L$ where $L=\operatorname{lcm}(m_1, m_2)$. The above proof still works, because $L=\operatorname{lcm}(m_1, m_2)$ is one of the numbers that divide $\operatorname{lcm}(m_1, m_2)$.

Comment: Please note that :The text states that $L$ is l.c.m. and not just that it  divides l.c.m.I have mentioned this, in the earlier post, as given by the link.

Comment: I was asking for constraints on relative primality of $m_1, m_2$. The text mentions none, while if I look elsewhere (as in the Konrad's article mentioned), it states that as a must.

Comment: Well, obviously if $a\equiv b\pmod{\operatorname{lcm}(m_1,m_2)}$, then $a\equiv b\pmod L$ for any $L\mid\operatorname{lcm}(m_1,m_2)$, so any such divisor $L$ of $\operatorname{lcm}(m_1,m_2)$ would satisfy your condition. Or, possibly, the condition you stated should've been equivalence ($\Longleftrightarrow$) rather than implication ($\implies$), in which case, true, $L=\operatorname{lcm}(m_1,m_2)$.

Comment: No, the text states as : "If..., then...". So, it is implication, and not equivalence.

Comment: @jitender Any $a,b$ will give you some constraint on $L$. The condition on relative primality is important for something else: if you want to solve 
 the system $a\equiv b_1\pmod{m_1}$ and $a\equiv b_2\pmod{m_2}$ for $a$, then $\gcd(m_1,m_2)=1$ will ensure you always have a solution, and it will be unique $\pmod{\operatorname{lcm}(m_1,m_2)}$ - Chinese remainder theorem (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chinese_remainder_theorem)

Comment: @jitender I've now had a look at your previous question and the excerpt from the book - they just claim $L$ *can* be taken as $\operatorname{lcm}(m_1,m_2)$, i.e. $\operatorname{lcm}(m_1,m_2)$ is *one* such $L$. They are not looking for any further constraints on either $m_1$, $m_2$ or $L$, apparently.

Comment: @jitender I am sorry I don't have much time to do it right now. Maybe later? I will get back to you.

Comment: Yes, you are correct for $L$, and no other constraints too. Also, as stated in the post, $b_1=b_2$. It is from the page #55 of Griifin Harriet book on Elementary Number theory. The book is heavily biased towards congruences. Also, on page 81 of the text, there is a mention of this specific case under 'Simultaneous linear congruences', just after the section for CRT. Can you please provide me any practical example. That would help me to understand the case better.

Comment: @jitender Here is an example (does it help?): What are the conditions that $x\equiv 5\pmod 4$ and $x\equiv 5\pmod 6$? This means that $x-5$ is divisible by both $4$ and $6$, which is the same as saying that $x-5$ is divisible by $\operatorname{lcm}(4,6)=12$. Thus, this is the same as saying $x\equiv 5\pmod{12}$. Of course, this then also implies that $x\equiv 5\pmod L$ for all $L\mid 12$, i.e. for all $L\in\{1,2,3,4,6,12\}$.

Comment: I am elaborating the example, please vet: It means that $x-5$ is in the same equivalence class w.r.t. the set of divisors of $12$. So, $\forall k \in \mathbb{Z}, x-5=k=2k=3k=4k=6k=12k$. Taking values of $k$ only for first two positive integers, (i) $k=1 :: x-5 =1.12=2.6=3.4=4.3=6.2=12.1$; (ii) $k=2 :: x-5 =1.24=2.12=3.8=4.6=6.4=12.2$; & so on for -ve integer values of $k$, and also trivially for $k=0$. In (i), values taken by $x$ are: $17, 29, 41,...$, while the other term is constant at $5$. Similarly, for case (ii). I mean that need both variable $x$, and constant $5$ in same residue class.